# Java class validation with annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I'm using Spring Boot.

I'm writing a Java class and I would like to make a validation using the annotations.
Something like this:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Validated
public class User {

    @NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be empty")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email address cannot be empty")
    @Email(message = "Please provide valid email address")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "First Name cannot be empty")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Last Name cannot be empty")
    private String lastName;
}
```

I would like to rise an exception if I try to create a new object with wrong parameters.
Same result if I will try to use a setter with wrong parameter.

Is it' possible? Is my code wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to use javax.validation for that, its not possible, if the @Validated and the validation annotations come from another source maybe, provide more information please

Comment: I'm using javax.validation so I understand that it's not possible. What is the best practice about it? Is it a 'manual' implementation about the fields validation?

Comment: AFAIK, spring validation works with REST requests and JPA entities validation out of the box.

Comment: I'm not using this class for Rest/JPA entities

Comment: @Safari typically if you want to validate anything when a setter is invoked and when the object is instantiated, you will write on the setters the validations by hand using a system that do not relys in cdi. Then in the constructor use the same validations, returning an IllegalArgumentException if any of the parameters is not valid

Comment: You can use javax validation to validate already instantiated objects or with the integration with jax-rs json documents that are going to be serialized into objects. It is also possible to validate method arguments with the @Valid annotation but no the instantiation of and object or the invocation usign a setter

Comment: If this is going to be something specific for certain object you can use the Factory pattern and after generating the objects, use the javax.validation Validation factory to validate the object that you have generated before returning it. But if the object is mutable you are screw because the setter will not validate the content using the annotations. My safe bet is write the validations in a static class and invoke the validations in the setters / constructor thorwing and IlegalArgumentException

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke validator by yourself

```
@Component   
class SomeComponent{

 private Validator validator;

 SomeComponent(Validator validator){
   this.validator = validator;
 }

 void validateInput(Input input) {
   
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Input>> violations = validator.validate(input);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
      throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }
  }
}
```

You can trigger in Post Constructor method and in setters

Answer (score -1):

You can use Hibernate Validator for Annotation validations
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createmodel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No, this system cannot be used to validate object instantiation, it work in other escenarios but not the specified one